# Random Variables Question, of the topic of probability of one side having a greater dice roll.

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, dice

I will post the Question and the specific part of the Mark scheme I have an issue with verbatim below to ensure my question is understood, I don't understand the logic behind a specific part of the mark schemes answer.

In the game of Risk, rolling six-sided dice decide the outcome of battles. Suppose that there are two players, red and blue. The red player rolls three dice $X_1, X_2, X_3$; and the blue player rolls two dice $Y_1, Y_2$. Whichever player rolls the highest number on a single die is declared the winner. In the event of
a tie, the blue player is declared the winner. Assume independence between dice rolls.

(a). Let $X$ and $Y$ be the highest number rolled by the red and blue player. What is the probability mass function of $X$? What is the pmf of $Y$?

(b). What is the probability that the red player wins?

So, my issue is with the answer to logic to the answer in part $(b)$ where it says:
The probability that the red player wins is
$$P(Y < X) = P(Y ≤ X − 1)$$
Why is it that subtracting the range of values of the Random variable $X$ results in $Y$ being less than or equal to $X-1$, what about when $Y = 3$ and $X = 5$, would $X$ not still win and thus should be included in the calculation of the probability.

I believe my question is: shouldn't the probability include the cases where $Y \leq X - n$ where $n = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to account for all cases where $X$ is greater than $Y$?

A proof is also included which may help but I don't fully understand it so perhaps an explanation of the logic behind the proof will suffice in answering my question.

[Proof of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlEqg.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't understand your question.  In your example, $(X, Y)=(5,3)$ we certainly do have $Y≤X-1$ so $X$ has a victory.  What's the problem?  It's a sometimes useful fact about integers that $n<m$ is the same as $n≤m-1$.  All that says is that if one integer is less than another, the distance between them has to be at least $1$.  No such claim can be made for rationals, say.

Comment: What I find objectionable in the quoted question is that it gives an inaccurate description of the rules of Risk. There's nothing wrong with basing a question on the rules they describe, just don't invoke the name of a game whose rules are different. It puts someone who actually knows the rules of Risk at a disadvantage.

Comment: The wording of your question suggests that you are reading $Y \leq X - 1$ the same as $Y = X - 1$. Actually these are two very different statements. Carefully considering how $Y \leq X - 1$ actually is different from $Y = X - 1$, are you still unsure why it is true that $P(Y < X) = P(Y \leq X − 1)$? If so, please edit the question to make your point of confusion clearer. Why do you think the case $X = 5$ and $Y = 3$ is not included in the probability $P(Y \leq X − 1)$?